# How do I set my iframe height to maximum instead of scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, iframe

I am wondering why my code down below, my height is set to 150px. I want to set my iframe height same as my content so that I don't need to scroll.

I am using react but I assume it is the same for plain javascript and React.

MY source code:

```css
.iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<iframe class="iframe" srcdoc="<div style='text-align: center;'>
hi<br/>hi<br/>hi<br/>hi<br/>hi<br/>hi<br/>hi<br/>hi<br/>hi<br/>hi<br/>hi<br/>hi<br/>hi<br/>hi<br/>hi<br/>hi<br/>hi<br/>hi<br/>hi<br/>hi<br/>hi<br/>hi<br/>
</div>"></iframe>
```

As you can see, I need to scroll. I want my height to be 100%. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this function to your JavaScript and your iframe will adjust to the height of its content.

```js
function resizeFrame(object) {
    object.style.height = object.contentWindow.document.documentElement.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
```

and call the function onload in the markup, like so:

```html
<iframe onload="resizeFrame(this)">{$content}</iframe>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/698pfz1w/

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this in :

```css
.iframe-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  position: relative;
}
 
.iframe-container iframe {
   border: 0;
   height: 100%;
   left: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="iframe-container">
  <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/KMYrIi_Mt8A" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

tell me if it changes something

Comment: That sets the height to be 100% of the view port  but I want the height to be same as  the content. So it might be bigger than 100% of view port or smaller than 100% of view port depending on the contnet.